Copy activity and query with new Salesforce connector
I have a Copy activity with the old Salesforce connector (as Source) with the following query:
@concat('SELECT * FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate > ''', replace(activity('AccountLookupDelta').output.firstRow.latest_insert, 'T', ' '), '''') 
Now I need to replace this Copy activity with the new Salesforce (SalesforceV2Object) connector. Here we can use a query with two options: 'Object-API/Rapport Id' and 'SOQL-query'.
My question is: How can I rewrite my previous query (with the old connector) such that it can be used with the new connector?
Replacing * in the query by FIELDS(ALL) does not work, even though this is how it should be in a SOQL query.

In new salesforce connector we use Bulk API 2.0 to query and ingest data As per this MS document
As per salesforce document FIELDS(ALL) is not supported for Bulk API 2.0

You can query with FIELDS(STANDARD) and manually add all field name in the query like below:
SELECT column1,column2,........ FROM Account

